# How to run three js with node js plus typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, three.js

I am trying to run three.js  i have initialized my project with typescript following this link [Nodejs setup with typescript](https://khalilstemmler.com/blogs/typescript/node-starter-project/) my package.json looks like this

```
{
  "name": "devopsplatform",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start:dev": "npx nodemon",
    "build": "rimraf ./build && tsc && npx vite",
    "start": "npm run build && node build/index.js "
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/neetesshhr/DevOpsPlatform.git"
  },
  "author": "Nitesh Rijal",
  "license": "ISC",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/neetesshhr/DevOpsPlatform/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/neetesshhr/DevOpsPlatform#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^18.15.11",
    "@types/three": "^0.150.0",
    "@types/webgl2": "^0.0.7",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
    "rimraf": "^4.4.1",
    "ts-node": "^10.9.1",
    "typescript": "^5.0.3",
    "vite": "^4.2.1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "three": "^0.151.2"
  }
}
```

and i have tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",                          
    "module": "commonjs",                    
    "lib": ["es6"],                     
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "build",                          
    "rootDir": "src",
    "strict": true,         
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "types": [
      "node",
      "three"
    ]
  }
}
```

I have just put `index.ts` in `src` folder `src/index.ts` and have only done in index.ts file  `import * as THREE from 'three';` and tried out `npm i`  and also put `index.html` in my root dir which looks like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>My first three.js app</title>
        <style>
            body { margin: 0; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="module" src="build/index.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

after running `npm start build`  i am facing error

```
-----

node_modules/@types/webxr/index.d.ts:1066:19 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'GLsizei'.

1066         numViews: GLsizei,
                       ~~~~~~~

node_modules/@types/webxr/index.d.ts:1092:11 - error TS2304: Cannot find name 'Element'.

1092     root: Element;
               ~~~~~~~


Found 184 errors in 47 files.

Errors  Files
    15  node_modules/@types/three/src/audio/Audio.d.ts:7
     2  node_modules/@types/three/src/audio/AudioAnalyser.d.ts:8
     2  node_modules/@types/three/src/audio/AudioContext.d.ts:5
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/audio/AudioListener.d.ts:8
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/audio/PositionalAudio.d.ts:4
     6  node_modules/@types/three/src/core/GLBufferAttribute.d.ts:22
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/extras/ImageUtils.d.ts:32
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/AnimationLoader.d.ts:11
     5  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/AudioLoader.d.ts:9
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/BufferGeometryLoader.d.ts:12
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/CompressedTextureLoader.d.ts:11
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/CubeTextureLoader.d.ts:11
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/DataTextureLoader.d.ts:11
     5  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/FileLoader.d.ts:7
     5  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/ImageBitmapLoader.d.ts:17
     6  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/ImageLoader.d.ts:13
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/LoaderUtils.d.ts:2
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/MaterialLoader.d.ts:17
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/ObjectLoader.d.ts:17
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/loaders/TextureLoader.d.ts:15
     6  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/WebGLRenderer.d.ts:28
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLAttributes.d.ts:7
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLBindingStates.d.ts:12
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLBufferRenderer.d.ts:8
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLCapabilities.d.ts:7
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLExtensions.d.ts:4
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLGeometries.d.ts:8
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLIndexedBufferRenderer.d.ts:2
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLInfo.d.ts:7
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLObjects.d.ts:2
     2  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram.d.ts:17
     2  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLShader.d.ts:1
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLState.d.ts:47
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLTextures.d.ts:10
     4  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLUniforms.d.ts:5
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLUniformsGroups.d.ts:9
     2  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webgl/WebGLUtils.d.ts:4
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/renderers/webxr/WebXRManager.d.ts:15
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/CanvasTexture.d.ts:18
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/CompressedArrayTexture.d.ts:10
     2  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/CompressedTexture.d.ts:27
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/Data3DTexture.d.ts:5
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/DataArrayTexture.d.ts:5
     3  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/DataTexture.d.ts:20
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/Texture.d.ts:35
     1  node_modules/@types/three/src/textures/VideoTexture.d.ts:17
    62  node_modules/@types/webxr/index.d.ts:76
```

I am new to three js please help me out to run this Thanks my node version is

```
$ node -v
v19.8.1
```

I am on ubuntu 22.04 lts OS